# display all unicode characters

Tags: unicode, character-set

When I open 'Character Map', not all characters are displayed.
For example in script 'balinese' the first character is displayed like this:

```
 __
|1B|
|00|
```

But I want the real character, of course. Do I lack fonts? If so is there a meta package?

Additional details:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Please add some details like version of ubuntu, ...

Comment: @Jan Please be specific about the details you need, I have no idea.

Comment: Have you tried to add the related language in Setting > Language Pack?

Answer (score 2):

To display a character you need a font that contains this character. This is also for the character map.

No font contains all Unicode characters (which are approximatly 1.000.000).

So install a font containing the unicode block you want to display and select this font in the character map. Then the character should be displayed.

Comment: Unicode has about 1,000,000 *code positions*. The number of *allocated* positions is currently about 100,000 (and not all of them correspond to graphic characters). But even this is more than any single font *can* contain, with the current font technology.

Comment: Related: http://unicode-table.com